# How to convert SQL statatement containing a "NOT IN" constraint to its equivalent LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I've been using Linq for about a year and I have only a rudemntary understanding of SQL.  So the following problem might be trite, and I appologize for that now.  But at work I've been asked to figure out the most performant way to use linq on the following sql. and I need some help.

I have a Client table and a ClientParticiaption table.  The ClientParticiaption table identifies Clients that particpate in a special training program.  I need to determine which Client's are not participating in the special training program.  Here's the SQL that works:

```
SELECT *
FROM Client
WHERE ClientControlID NOT IN
(
  SELECT ClientControlID
  FROM ClientParticipation
)
```

I'm having trouble converting this to its equivalent linq statement.  I think I should be using the Except operator but I'm not sure how in this case.  Any thoughts would be very helpful.

Here's what I'm currently doing, which works, but I suspect this is not very effecient.  Note, I'm using Entity Framework and I may have incorrectly assumed that resolving this issue has nothing to do with EF.

```
IList<int> clientControlIDs =
    ClientArngmt.Select(
    cac => cac.ClientControlID ).ToList();

IList<int> particiaptionClientArngmtIDs =
    Participations.Select(
    cap => cap.ClientArngmtID ).ToList();

IEnumerable<int> notParticipatingClientArngmtIDs =
    clientArngmtIDs.Except(
    particiaptionClientArngmtIDs );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st solution:

```
ClientArngmt
 .Where(c => !Participations.Select(p => p.ClientArngmtID).Contains(c.ClientControlID))
 .Select(c => c);
```

2nd solution:

```
Participations
 .Where(p => !p.Clients.Any()) // Just assuming Clients is the ObjectSet name for ClientArngmt
 .SelectMany(p => p.Clients)
 .Distinct(); // If you want to get them distinct
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just coded solution 1 and am trying it out, but I have to move onto something else for a couple of hours so I won't get to test until later this afternoon.  I will send a comment once I test.  Thanks again.

Comment: @martin-jasper u r welcome, hope it helps you, waiting for your comment

Comment: @PrOfessOrX The first solution works great. I ran my sql profiler and found that the first solution only sent one message to the sql server to calculate the results. Nice and effecient. Thanks again.

Comment: Doesn't the second solution just return an empty enumerable? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

you can use a where statement such as

```
        IList<Client> clients = (from cac in ClientArngmt
                                 where !(Participations.Select(cap => ClientArngmtID).Contains(cac.ClientControlID))
                                 select cac).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, I might just be muddled today, where do you propose I use this statement?  Is it meant to replace my code?